# Attribute Error: str object - has no attribute days. Attempting to migrate my model

Tags: python, django

Have two models that I am attempting to override the save functions (parent and Child).
the models look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Program(models.Model):
    air_date             = models.DateField(default="0000-00-00")
    air_time             = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
    service              = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    block_time           = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
    block_time_delta     = models.DurationField(default="00:00:00")
    running_time         = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
    running_time_delta   = models.DurationField(default="00:00:00")
    remaining_time       = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
    remaining_time_delta = models.DurationField(default="00:00:00")
    title                = models.CharField(max_length=190)
    locked_flag          = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deleted_flag         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    library              = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=190,blank=True)
    mc                   = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=64)
    producer             = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=64)
    editor               = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=64)
    remarks              = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    audit_time           = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    audit_user           = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=32)

    def calculate_time(self):
      total_run_time_delta = timedelta(minutes=0)
      hold_remaining_delta = models.DurationField()
      for segs in self.segments.all():
        total_run_time_delta += segs.length_time_delta
      self.running_time_delta = total_run_time_delta
      self.running_time = f"{self.running_time_delta}"
      self.remaining_time_delta = self.block_time_delta - total_run_time_delta
      self.remaining_time = f"{abs(self.remaining_time_delta)}"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.calculate_time()
      super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pk} : {self.title}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('program_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
        #return reverse('program-update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Segment(models.Model):
    program_id = models.ForeignKey(Program,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='segments',   #new link to Program
    )
    sequence_number = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=6,default="0.00")
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=190)
    bridge_flag     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    length_time     = models.TimeField(null=True,default=None, blank=True)
    length_time_delta = models.DurationField(default="00:00:00")
    author          = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    voice           = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    library         = models.CharField(max_length=190,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    summary         = models.TextField()
    audit_time      = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    audit_user      = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=32)

    def save( self, *args, **kwargs):
      program = Program.object.get(id=self.program_id)
      super().save(*args,**kwargs)
      program.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author
```

After python manage.py make migrations (which works by the way),
I try to migrate and get this...

cmd$ python manage.py migrate

( ... bunch of errors ... )
File "/Users/toadyb/.local/share/virtualenvs/trackx_proj-eoegj60O/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/duration.py", line 44, in duration_microseconds
return (24 * 60 * 60 * delta.days + delta.seconds) * 1000000 + delta.microseconds
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'days'

Anybody know why I am getting this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Default value for `DateField/TimeField/DateTimeField` should be instance of `datetime datetime or date or time`. I think in some cases you are trying to get default value of that fields, and from default you are getting string, not datetime object

Comment: Yeah,   I see what you are getting at,  but that doesn't change a thing.....still get the error.  I changed the default to  models.DurationField(default=timedelta) - for all of the delta variables, but get the same error...  The other date fields were working just fine.  It isn't until I added the delta's that the model would not migrate.

Comment: Got it to migrate - had to back out all of the previous migrations but now won't let me subtract. Error is:   File "/Users/toadyb/Desktop/trackx_proj/trackx_root/trackx_site/models.py", line 32, in calculate_time
    self.remaining_time_delta = self.block_time_delta - total_run_time_delta
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'DurationField'